# Loops bug with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello i help an friend to move his website and i have this bug ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on the web page i think is the .htaccess file but not sure

here is the .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\/resource.*$
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ /index.php [L]
FallbackResource /index.php
```

I think ist the fallbackResource but not not sure .
did you have somes idea how this loop is caused ?

Comment: If you suspect the `FallbackResource` is the cause of the loop, then what happens if you comment it out?

Comment: For sure this implementation is strange in a number of aspects ...

Comment: What URL are you requesting? What is the redirect loop you are seeing? There is no redirect loop in the code you posted (there are no redirects at all). The FallbackResource directive looks redundant (and would override the mod_rewrite rule for resource requests) and should probably be deleted altogether.

Comment: If the site is being "moved", did it work previously with this config? What has changed?

Comment: If you use `FallbackResource` and you don't have further rules, you don't need mod_rewrite at all. You can get rid of `RewriteEngine`, `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`. If you have more undisclosed rules, you'll need to share them too.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Not necessarily in this case. In the rules above the mod_rewrite directives are performing a subtly different task than `FallbackResource` (they are rewriting requests for actual files). Without knowing more about the application, it is the `FallbackResource` directive that looks redundant (as I mentioned above). However, this does still perform an action in that it "rewrites" requests for non-existent "resources" to `/index.php` (which is otherwise excluded from the rule above). Although mixing `FallbackResource` and mod_rewrite in this way is probably not recommended.